# Data only partially displayed in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I loaded ACLED-Data as delimited text data into QGIS to count the number of points in a multi-polygon. However, only a fraction (100- 200 points) of the imported data is displayed and processed by QGIS. More unintuitively, if I check the attribute table, the data looks fine.

To check if something is off with my data, I checked it via R and according to my test 6000+ points should actually be displayed in QGIS from which 1142 have a unique location, meaning the reason for my problem does not seem to bee that point are just overlaying...

Here is how I loaded and checked my code  in R:

```
ACLED <- read.csv("ACLED_NEW.csv")
ACLED%>%
  filter(year > 2007, year < 2015)%>%
  distinct(latitude,longitude)%>%
  count()
```

The Data can be found here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1V3fElBxXkjcDeU74Ypp0H5WAZNA1oUEg?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is clearly wrong with the Lat/Long coordinates. These numbers make no sense:

[image: latitude longitude columns]

Furthermore, to create a spatial points `sf` object from a csv file in R you would do something like:

```
library(sf) 
ACLED <- read.csv("ACLED_NEW.csv")
ACLED_sf <- st_as_sf(ACLED, coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs = xxxx)
```

but what is the coordinate reference system (`crs = ??`) of these coordinates. Looks like a mixture :-(

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded the data again and now it looks fine!

Answer (score 1):

From the data, it is understood that the issue is with your coordinates. You have probably taken a UTM zone and many of your points fall outside the zone. Hence they show negative values. Still, you should try

> Right Click on the layer -> Zoom to layer

This zooms to all the data points in that layer. Still, you need to correct your coordinates.